# Async mocha, chai test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm running the following test:

```
it("validates data", (done) => {
    Data.run( function(success: boolean) { 
        expect(success).equal(true);
        done();
    });
});
```

When I run the tests this works correctly I get something like this:

```
 ✓ validates data (194ms)
```

However the program never exits until I press `cmd+C` is that the expected behaviour? When I run any other test with out a callback it exists after all tests are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Mocha 4 issue, the only solution they provide is to use the `--exit` flag. Something like:

`mocha --require ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts --exit`

Not ideal, but works for now.